# Is there an option to look at the exact front of a face?

Tags: camera

Is there an option to look at the exact front of a face? I want to put the file on a beamer to draw it big and make it out of wood.

Comment: it's not clear to me, could you try to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Like I want to look at the exact front of a face to display it with a beamer and draw it on a piece of plywood

Comment: If you want to have a view orthogonal to a face you need to select the face in Edit mode and press shift 7, is it what you want

Comment: hmm then my belder puts the stuff upside down

Comment: and can you see how much you are zoomed in?

Comment: It won't move the object, it will only put the view in face of the face. What do you mean about "how much you are zoomed in"?

Comment: Like the percentage of zoom

Comment: I didn't know there was a zoom percentage, I'm not sure why you would need it? If you want to come back to a precise view you can use the camera: to align the camera to the current view press ctrl alt 0. If you want your camera to be orthographic, go in its settings and choose Orthographic instead of Perspective.

Comment: OK :D and thanks for the other tips I put my whole 3d model upside down and now it works :D

Comment: oh ok nice then  ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help now I can start building my real sized lambo ;)

Comment: Is there an option to look thru things that are in the way?

Comment: maybe alt Z is what you're looking for (Blender 2.8)?

Comment: Yes it was thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 1):

To align the view to a face you need to select the face in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>. To align the camera to the view press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. If you want your camera to be orthographic, select it, go in the *Properties* editor > *Data* > *Lens* and choose *Orthographic* instead of *Perspective*.